# 'All this' vs 'All these'

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

What's difference between these two and where should I use them.

For ex. That mobile is cheap. It has front and rear camera. **All this makes** it a good phone.

What should I use here. `All this makes` or `All these make` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All this is Kim's](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34055/all-this-is-kims)

Answer (score 4):

*All these* is not an idiom and is not used in the same way as *all this*.

It is better to say *all these things* or *all these features* or *all these reasons*.

In your example, *all this* is more appropriate. *All this* can be used to refer to multiple things, even though *this* implies something singular. When you use *all this*, think of it as meaning *all this stuff*.

The following examples are common and perfectly valid:

> The mobile phone is cheap. It has a good battery. It has front and rear cameras. **All this** makes it a good choice.
>
> The mobile phone is cheap. It has a good battery. It has front and rear cameras. **All these features** make it a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is for singular whereas These is for plural. Since you are referring to both front and rear camera it is plural. Other than that, there are two cameras: front and rear. So you should write cameras instead of camera. Your final sentence would be:

That mobile is cheap. It has front and rear cameras. All these make it a good phone.